# How you evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}\left(1 + \sqrt{3\cdot4} + \sqrt[3]{4\cdot5\cdot6} + \ldots + \sqrt[n]{(n+1)(n+2)\ldots(2n)}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

How you evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}\left(1 + \sqrt{3\cdot4} + \sqrt[3]{4\cdot5\cdot6} + \ldots + \sqrt[n]{(n+1)(n+2)\ldots(2n)}\right)$

I have been with this problem all day and I dont know how to solve it, I tried with Slotz, but didn't get any answer. Computing it I have got  0.7362

Comment: Please edit the post to include your efforts. Or I'm afraid your question might be downvoted/closed.

Comment: Hint: By Stolz–Cesàro theorem you have to compute $$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \frac{{\sqrt[n]{{(n + 1)(n + 2) \cdots (2n)}}}}{{2n - 1}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \frac{1}{{2n - 1}}\sqrt[n]{{\frac{{(2n)!}}{{n!}}}} =\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \frac{{4n}}{{2n - 1}}\frac{{\Big( {\frac{{\sqrt[{2n}]{{(2n)!}}}}{{2n}}} \Big)^2 }}{{\frac{{\sqrt[n]{{n!}}}}{n}}}.
$$

Comment: put another way, term $n$  is about $ \frac{4}{e}  n,$ by Stiring,  so the limit is $ \frac{4}{n^2 \; e}  (1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n)$   or $\frac{2}{e} $

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Stolz theorem and definite integral
Let:
$$
\begin{align*}
A&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1+\sqrt{3\cdot4}+\ldots+\sqrt[n]{(n+1)(n+2)\ldots(2n)}}{n^2} \\
A&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sqrt[n]{(n+1)(n+2)\ldots(2n)}}{n^2-(n-1)^2}\\
A&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{2}\cdot\sqrt[n]{(1+\frac{1}{n})(1+\frac{2}{n})\ldots(1+\frac{n}{n})}
\end{align*}
$$
Let:
$$
\begin{align*}
B&=\sqrt[n]{(1+\frac{1}{n})(1+\frac{2}{n})\ldots(1+\frac{n}{n})}\\
\ln(B)&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\ln(1+\frac{i}{n})\\
C&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\ln (B)=\int_{0}^{1}\ln(1+x)dx\\
C&=(1+x)\ln(1+x)|_{0}^{1}-x|_{0}^{1}=2\ln(2)-1
\end{align*}
$$
Hence:
$$
\begin{align*}
A&=\frac{2}{e}
\end{align*}
$$